# Confused with Html Image Height and Width

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I am a little confused about html `IMG` tag's height and width and the CSS/STYLE Height and Width

```
<img  alt="Title" src="/someimageurl" style="width:150px" width="150" />
```

You can see that I have set the `width` attribute using `style` as well as `width` attribute for Image. When we use an Image are these two the same attributes that we are setting or are they different?
If they are different then please explain in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. No difference between CSS width and HTML width. You shouldn't style a website nowadays with HTML-tags anymore. Use CSS for this.

Comment: In HTML5 there is a difference: the `width=""` and `height=""` attributes are now used to inform the browser of the image's **intrinsic size** which is independent from the `<img>` element's box size which is controlled by CSS's `width:` and `height:` properties (but could also be controlled by `position` and flex-box rules as well).

Answer (score 1):

The `width` attribute is an obsolete way to specify width. You can only specify width in pixels using it.

From the other hand, the style width is the modern way for specifying width, not only for images, but for any html element. You can specify width in pixels, points, percents and may other units.

The same applies to the `height`.

Comment: No, specifying width and height with percent values is also possible with the HTML attributes. No unit means pixels, "50%" means fifty percent.

Answer (score 1):

Setting those values per CSS takes precedent over giving them via HTML attributes – so setting them to different values would normally make little sense.

One could argue that setting them via HTML attributes makes the browser know the image dimensions – and therefor the space he has to reserve while rendering the page when the image is not loaded yet – even earlier; but I doubt that this argument would hold up in reality, since rendering in modern browsers AFAIK usually starts only when the CSS is already loaded, and anyway the CSS will most likely influence the whole page layout drastically, so even if the browser was to reserver image space only knowing the HTML at first, he would have to re-render most of the page once the CSS is applied.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same but if you define like that the last one you define in html would take the width by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML attribute `width="150"` and the CSS declaration `width:150px`, when applied to the same `img` element, usually have the same effect (so specifying both is redundant), but they are not the same thing.

The HTML attribute causes the element node, in the document tree, to have the property `width` set to the value `150`. The CSS declaration, when appearing in the `style` attribute value as here, causes the `width` property of the `style` property of the element node to get the value `150px`. When rendering the document, the browser uses the `width` value, interpreted as m (and scales the image to that width if its intrinsic width is different), *unless* CSS is enabled, in which case the CSS cascade is applied, resulting in the value of `150px` to be used.

So if the values were different, the one in the `style` attribute would win in CSS-enabled browsers.

The HTML attribute value must be a pure number (with pixel as the implied unit) or a percentage. In the CSS declaration, many other units are allowed, too, e.g. the `em` unit that lets you scale an image in proportion to font size (useful for small images presented in text), though you would normally then scale the *height* rather than width. In such cases, you could use the HTML attribute as a fallback (for situations where CSS is disabled), based on a guess of a typical font size, e.g. `<img ... height=18 style="height: 1em">`.